# How to show Command bar menu at desired position?

Tags: c#, uwp

We can expand flyout menut at desired position as..

```
FrameworkElement senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
myFlyout.ShowAt(sender as UIElement, e.GetPosition(sender as UIElement));
```

But, How to expand Command bar menu at desired position? Any workaround? IsOpen propery opens the commandbar only at its default right/left/top of the app! I want to open it near my desired control/position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CommandBar` does not provide `ShowAt` method to show the Command bar menu placed in relation to the specified element.

If you want to expand Command bar menu at desired position, you should be able to put the `AppBarButton` in the `Flyout` instead of put `AppBarButton` in the  `CommandBar.SecondaryCommands`.

You can add `Opening` event of the `CommandBar` and use `ShowAt` method to show the `Flyout` in the event. When you set the `IsOpen` propery of `CommandBar` to `true`, the `Opening` event will be fired.

For example:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <CommandBar x:Name="MyCommandBar"  Width="800" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Opening="MyCommandBar_Opening">
        <CommandBar.Resources>
            <Flyout x:Name="MyBtnFly" Placement="Right">
                <StackPanel>
                    <AppBarButton x:Name="CommandBarAppBarButton" Icon="Like" Label="Like" />
                    <AppBarButton Icon="Dislike" Label="Dislike" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Flyout>
        </CommandBar.Resources>
        <AppBarToggleButton Icon="Shuffle" Label="Shuffle"  />
        <AppBarToggleButton Icon="RepeatAll" Label="Repeat" />
        <AppBarSeparator/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Back" />
        <AppBarButton Icon="Stop" Label="Stop" />
        <AppBarButton Icon="Play" Label="Play" />
        <AppBarButton Icon="Forward" Label="Forward" />
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <TextBlock Text="Now playing..." Margin="12,14"/>
        </CommandBar.Content>
    </CommandBar>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MyText" Tapped="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="Click"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyCommandBar.IsOpen = true;
}

private void MyCommandBar_Opening(object sender, object e)
{
    FrameworkElement senderElement = MyText as FrameworkElement;
    MyBtnFly.ShowAt(senderElement);
}
```